# How to get the current folder of js?

Tags: javascript, html, directory

THe point is that I need to open an .html file in new window. For this I do the following:

```
this.opendoc = function () {
    var h = 500, w = 500;
    var billhref = '/pages/bill.html';
    var openedwidow = window.open(billhref, '', 'scrollbars=1,height='+Math.min(h, screen.availHeight)+',width='+Math.min(w, screen.availWidth)+',left='+Math.max(0, (screen.availWidth - w)/2)+',top='+Math.max(0, (screen.availHeight - h)/2));                       
};
```

the billhref is placed in the folder with my porject, but running `opendoc` I get 404.
Actually I don't know the structure of crm for which I do this, I think getting the path of executing `.js` will help me to get a vision of the current folder structure and make the appropriate changes in my code.

Comment: Maybe `var billhref = 'pages/bill.html'`. With the starting `/` means relative to root.

Comment: @Leo unfortunately, this way forwards me to the main page of crm

Comment: can you show us your project folder structure? What type of server are you on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var billhref = '../pages/bill.html'
```

this goes up one level (the root folder) and gets > `pages` > `bill.html`